# Is there a way to define a range when using page_sections?

Tags: ruby, watir, page-object-gem

My page has few divs in block layout with same class names. There is an outer div with an id and I have defined this outer div as a page-section. Each of the inner divs forms a block section and except the first page_section(index: 0), I want the access the rest of them as page_sections.

```
class MainHTML
  include PageObject

  page_section(:outer_div, BlockSection, id: 'block_section_id')
end


class BlockSection
  include PageObject

  page_section(:first_block, PrimaryBlock, class: 'block-class', index: 0)
  page_sections(:remaining_blocks, SecondaryBlocks, class: 'block-class', index: [1..-1])
end
```

Is there a way to define a range [1..-1] when declaring page_sections like above?